# Facing issue on Azure App service

Tags: .net, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans, azure-app-service-envrmnt

Hi I have hosted my app on Azure app service. Recently I came across some issues

1) When site stops responding error we get "Connection time out"

2) So for above issue I restarted site from Azure portal. It starts working again.

After some time again step#1 issue occurs.

3) I tried to resolve from checking diagnostic and logs which I got as follows:

```
#Fields: date time s-sitename cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Cookie) cs(Referer) cs-host sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status sc-bytes cs-bytes time-taken

#2018-06-06 04:53:25 testsite GET /HeaderMaster/index "something" 80 - "MY_IP" Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/67.0.3396.62+Safari/537.36
- - mytestsite.azurewebsites.net 500 121 0 463 1273 230012
```

Any idea why this is happening. I have kept 2 websites under same plan whose size (quota) is showing

devsite 554MB

testsite 440MB

I also scaled up app service plan (Basic : medium) but still facing same issue.

Thanks

Regards
Kunal

Comment: Have you enable `Always On` in the Application settings?

Comment: I tried this but after 5 minutes again it is stopped. It is not reachable or page is loading. No luck. But my default page loads everytime. But if I tried to login from one URL with tokens etc. it some time works and some time not.

Comment: @JoyWangThis is weird!!!! After every 5 min I have to switch off Always on settings and again turn it on. Azure app service is taking my hours away. really Weird issue!!!

Comment: I will suggest you use kudu and you should be able to find the log files under the debug console. Please check if there are any failure logs.

Comment: @ZahidFaroq I tried to check from FTP --> /LogFiles/kudu/trace
There are only two types of files are found
2018-06-06T06-53-59_1e46c0_001_Startup_GET__0s &
2018-06-06T07-00-32_1e46c0_002_Shutdown_0s

I don't understand whats wrong with this? Please help me to resolve.

Comment: Check the link below this might help. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-troubleshoot-performance-degradation